# Return first element of the tuple

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Suppose I create a function that adds two integers :

```
def addInt(a : Int, b: Int) : (Int, Int) = {
 | val x = a + b
 | (x,2)
 | }
```

I'm returning `(result, 2)` on purpose for the sake of this question.

Now I want to create a variable that returns only x.

```
val result = addInt(3,4) for example
```

result would return (7,2) but I only want it to return 7. How can I do this? (Without changing the code of the function obviously).

Comment: Just pick the first element of the tuple? `val (res, _) = addInt(3,4)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
val result = addInt(3,4)._1
```

And if you wanted the 2:

```
val the2 = addInt(3,4)._2
```

Answer (score 2):

Scala tuples have accessor methods for their elements called `_1`, `_2`, `_3`, and so on. So, to select the first element of the tuple, you would call `_1`:

```
someTuple._1
```

You can find the documentation for Scala's tuple class(es) in the [Scala API documentation](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple22.html).

Alternatively, you can also use pattern matching.

```
val result      = addInt(3, 4)._1
val (result, _) = addInt(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Scala 3, tuple elements can be accessed in this manner:

```
val result = addInt(3,4)(0) // first element of tuple
```