# how to find the tuple value using scala?

Tags: scala, tuples

**val x=(1,(2,(3,(4,5))))**

how the get the 4 from above using Scala?

can someone please to find the value using the Scala code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return first element of the tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46776254/return-first-element-of-the-tuple)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access individual elements of tuple [by position](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tuples.html#accessing-the-elements) with individual elements being named `_1`, `_2` etc. :

```
val four = x._2._2._2._1
```

Or using [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tuples.html#pattern-matching-on-tuples):

```
val (_,(_,(_,(four,_)))) = x
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use pattern matching to decompose the expression:

```scala
scala> val (a,(b,(c,(d,e)))) = (1,(2,(3,(4,5))))
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: Int = 3
d: Int = 4
e: Int = 5
```

In case you are not interested in other values than 4:

```scala
scala> val (_, (_, (_, (x, _)))) = (1,(2,(3,(4,5))))
x: Int = 4
```